# How can i add urdu language in ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to use Urdu Language with 'ckeditor', i am already using one java script library for this purpose but that's not working with 'ckeditor'.

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/Urdu-input
try this

Comment: i have tried this but it does not work for chrome and even other browsers it have errors

Comment: it does not show any text after i press ctrl + space then it started write english but does not write urdu